# Calculate Difference between two dates as a signed value

Tags: php

Am building a web application where administrator needs to know applicants that their duration of registration has expired.so i need to compare the present date with their expire date which i fecth from the database.I tried using the function date_diff(), but the problem with date_diff() is that if i have a date such as 2014-02-31 as my expiry date and i have 2014-03-01 then the present day is above the expiry date:so application has expired.but the function seems to return the same value when date is equally greater than or less than.

Here is my function

```
function CheckStatus($date)
{
    $date1 = new DateTime(date('Y-m-d'));
    $date2 = new DateTime($date);

    $interval = $date1->diff($date2);

    return $interval->format('%a');
}
```

Am just trying to know if todays date is greater than the expiry date so as to know then i know the applicant has expired.

Any help would be appriciated.
Thanks in advance

just got this example on php doc:

```
function CheckStatus($date)
{
//if expiry date is less than todays date
//then enrollee expired
    $date1 = new DateTime(date('Y-m-d'));
    $date2 = new DateTime($date);

    if($date1 > $date2)
    {
        echo '<span class="label-default label label-danger">expired</span>';
    }
    if($date1 < $date2)
    {
        echo '<span class="label-default label label-info">Running</span>';
    }
}
```

Does anyone think i would run into any issues with this; maybe later

Answer (score 1):

date_diff takes a keyword arg "absolute". Set this to false to get the result you're looking for.

Note that date_diff and $date->diff are aliases of the same function!

Edit: link to docs for convenience: http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php

Answer (score 0):

```
// assuming $date is a valid date string
function isExpired($date) {
    return time() > strtotime($date);
}
```