# Return time difference in minutes between two DateTime objects keeping the sign

Tags: php, datetime

I want to obtain the difference in minutes between two DateTime objects, and keep the sign.

I am using [date_diff()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php) alias of *DateTime::diff()*, which according to the docs accepts an argument to return absolute difference or not.

This question ([Calculate Difference between two dates as a signed value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26318811/calculate-difference-between-two-dates-as-a-signed-value)) is similar, and is actually what brought me to learn about the `$absolute` arg, which is default to false. But it's still not working.

```
$now = new DateTime('now');
$later = new DateTime('+15 minutes');
$before = new DateTime('-15 minutes');

$interval = date_diff($now, $later);
$interval_minutes = $interval->days * 24 * 60;
$interval_minutes += $interval->h * 60;
$interval_minutes += $interval->i;
echo 'Later:' . $interval_minutes;

$interval = date_diff($now, $before);
$interval_minutes = $interval->days * 24 * 60;
$interval_minutes += $interval->h * 60;
$interval_minutes += $interval->i;
echo 'Before:' . $interval_minutes;
```

Both results have the same sign *(positive)*.

What am I missing?

Thanks!

Comment: if($interval->invert) $interval_minutes *= -1; //The minus is coded in an extra property 'invert'

Comment: @jspit Well that is interesting. Solves the mystery. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @jspit's comment, I now know that the sign is contained within a property named "invert".

Hence, to apply the sign, one has to do:

```
// This continues below the code in the question

// Add the right sign
if($interval->invert){
    $interval_minutes *= -1;
}
```

From [the docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php):

> invert is 1 if the interval represents a negative time period and 0 otherwise.